# Login Activity with Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit

i am new to android and i try to understand the Retrofit library to use it in an login application but i can't make it work. Here is my sample code.

LoginAPI.java

```
  public interface LoginAPI {
   @POST("/login.php")
   public void getFeed(String username,String password,Callback<LoginResponse> response);

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
   login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
                    .build();


            LoginAPI api = restAdapter.create(LoginAPI.class);
            api.getFeed(username,password,new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Make retrofit calls on separate thread or AsyncTask and with existing code are you getting error? if yes post the log.

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Indeed you don't need to make the calls  on separate thread or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make retrofit calls on separate thread or AsyncTask

**Try this**

```
 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Thread fetch = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

               RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
                .build();


        LoginAPI api = restAdapter.create(LoginAPI.class);
        api.getFeed(username,password,new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                Log.d("Response","Logged In");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("Response","Failed");

            }
        });
    }
  }

 fetch.start();
});
```

Toast may not work from other thread use Log.d().

Comment: i try it but it gives me an error No Retrofit annotation found. If i put annotations i get the error message @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding....

Comment: Are you sure login.php REST call is responding correctly? Is it giving response? I mean retrofit call reaching.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing **annotations** in your interface, replace

```
public interface LoginAPI {
   @POST("/login.php")
   public void getFeed(String username,String password,Callback<LoginResponse> response);
}
```

with

```
public interface LoginAPI {
   @POST("/login.php")
   public void getFeed(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password")String password,Callback<LoginResponse> response);    
}
```

and check whether works or not

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to add the username and password as url parameters i.e.

```
?username=XXX&password=YYYY
```

change
    public interface LoginAPI {
       @POST("/login.php")
       public void getFeed(String username,String password,Callback response);
    }

with

```
public interface LoginAPI {
   @POST("/login.php")
   public void getFeed(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password,Callback<LoginResponse> response);    
}
```